# How to display a WordPress post based on ID for a Subdomain

Tags: wordpress, post, subdomain

I am trying to display a post based on ID for my subdomain. My domain service provider allows a subdomain to point only to a subdirectory. I want to show with this subdomain one single post of my current website.

Therefore I have made a subdirectory named "subdomain" and placed there an index.php with the following content

```
<?php 
    $_GET['page_id']= 3233; 
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
    require('../wp-blog-header.php' );
?>
```

The idea is that when subdomain is opened it would show directly the post with id 3233. However this is not happening. If the id used is from a page then everything functions. But it does not function for posts.

Can someone please help

Comment: if i understand what you are trying to achive, what you need is to go to edit post, and set the permanentlink

Comment: I am trying to display the post with id 3233. However with my index.php this is not possible as it only displays page  (when page id is given) and nothing when post id is given.